# How do I make my button clear the first two forms then when clicked again clear the last form?

Tags: javascript, html

Below I have attached the code that I have. I need help getting my button on click to clear the first two forms then when it is clicked again clear the last field that is left. Please any help on this. I have been trying different things but currently don't know how I would go about doing this. I am new to writing any type of code so this may be a simple task but I don't really know how to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Web Lock VPN Service</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
                background-image: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/7eRbJLwlltrqMGUleKadG70Dn4oapmr7xQordaJhrblNGjSxGaf4x1-6IzDaUiLv_BaFhkgTfuucGSjvGH6w41GyBLbMZqHwZTHJ7CQqWgqYpuB4oa0_1BTP32CFBf07PHb_cgZrpw=w2400");

        }
    </style>

    <script>
    </script>

    <!--EJD-5/11 added link to CSS style sheet-->

    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>

    <!--EJD-5/11 used "pre" to move VPN picture to roughly the center of the page-->

     <pre>                                                                                                                      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/8MOV9pJZ0HuFhWUEb5Qj2li8L_pspnylQ6rnTYH5wmLGgWjxAfEZ8hFIXv4MPUqFnkVtzSY8Jf0zuKKiHWyHumtnG6Zw_7y9dNbfns1lKrYQn9BCf05JU3pmHmIhEweJOlkOd21tXw=w2400" style="width:300px;height:200px;"> </a> 
        </pre>

      <pre><h1 id="bluetext">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          WebLock VPN Order Form </h1>
        </pre>

        <!--EJD 5/11 Added horizontal line for style-->
        <hr>
    </head>

    <body>


        <pre><h2 id="generaltext">                                                             Thank you for showing interest in Web Lock's VPN service! In order to purchase our product, please fill out the form below.</h2> 

            </pre>
            <!--EJD 5/11- Created a radio button form as a client survey-->
    <form name="survey" id="VPN">
        <h3>What is the most important aspect of a VPN for you?</h3>

        <p><input name="survey" type="radio" value="Small">Security</p>
        <p><input name="survey" type="radio" value="Small">Speed</p>
        <p><input name="survey" type="radio" value="Small">Price</p>
        <p><input name="survey" type="radio" value="Small">Platform Availability</p>
    </form>
        <!--EJD 5/11 Created a form for filling out information to be validated later-->
        <form required; name= "Module Selection" id="FT">

        <h3 id="generaltext">Select your features below:</h3>

        <p>
        <input name="modules" type="checkbox" value="HighspeedVPN">High Speed VPN </p>
        <p>
        <input name="modules" type="checkbox" value="Antivirus">Antivirus Addon </p>
        <p>
        <input name="modules" type="checkbox" value="WebShield">Browse-safe web shield </p>
        <p>
        <input name="modules" type="checkbox" value="TransactionGuard">Transaction Guard </p>

    </form>

        <h3 id="generaltext">Fill out your information below:</h3>
        <form required; name= "custinfo">
        <p>
        Name:&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp<input name="Name"size=:50 type="text"><br>
        </p> 
        <p>
        Email Address:&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp<input name="Emailaddress"size=:50 type="text"><br> 
        </p>
        <p>
        Street Address:&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp<input name="S_Address"size=:50 type="text"><br></p>
        <p>
        Address 2:&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp<input name="Address_2"size=:50 type="text"><br></p>      
        <p>
        Zip Code:&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp<input name="Zip"size=:50 type="text"><br>  
        <p>
        City:&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp<input name="City"size=:50 type="text"><br>     


        </form>

        <!--EJD 5/11 Created a drop-down list for states to choose-->

        <form name="states">

        State:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select required; name="states">


        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
        <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>


    </form>

    <!--EJD 5/11 created checkboxes for clients to order specific modules-->


    <!--EJD 5/11 added a text area for clients to comment-->
    <h3 id="generaltext">Questions and comments:</h3>
    <p>
    <textarea name= "Comments" rows="5" cols="80">

    </textarea>
    <!--EJD 5/11 Added a submit button and a clear button to tie to JS functions-->
    <p>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="dosubmit()">

    <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="doclear(); doclear2();"/>
        <script>
 function doclear() {
 document.getElementById("VPN").reset();
}         
  function doclear2(){
  document.getElementById("FT").reset();
            }
```

Comment: Place your script in  `<head>`, it should work

Comment: @NodirRashidov that is not my problem. How do I click the button a second time and have it clear the 3rd form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should declare a variable like **isFirstClear** with default = false, and add check condition in onClick button function:

```
if (!isFirstClear) {
    doclear();
    isFirstClear = true;
}
else {
    doclear2();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want my first button click to clear the first two forms then click it a second time to clear all forms.

Comment: just use the same logic @Rim Vo used here, it's easy. move doclear2() inside if, add doclear3() method and call it in else